# Values coming from the Web API 2 to the client are null after Serializing a Data transfer Object

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Class implementation

```
[Serializable]
public class Apple
{
    
    string name{get;set;}


}
```

this resides in the server side and from Web API 2 and is returning an apple object. If I do not use `serializable` attribute I am getting the correct values from the client's end but if I use Serialized I am getting null for the name . how may I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to specify [Serializable] attribute because Asp.Net WebApi serialize your public properties by default whether you specify or not. the reason why you are getting null object because your retuned json is not in normal form as it should be.

**First Solution:**
If you really want to use [Serializable] attribute then you need to configure [Serializer formatter (json or xml) in WebApi 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization) and you need to use [DataContract] and [DataMember] along with [Serializable].

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class Apple
{
   [DataMember]
   string name{get;set;}
}
```

**Second Solution:**
You can configure Serializer to ignore [Serializable] attribute. by doing this you don't have to add extra attribute with class as i have specified above.

```
var serializerSettings = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
var contractResolver = (DefaultContractResolver)serializerSettings.ContractResolver;
contractResolver.IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true;
```